# looping through form items using JQuery's .each and changing the src with .replace

Tags: jquery

I know how to do this using good old JavaScript but I want to reduce my code and get a better understanding of jQuery, so here' my problem:

I have a collection of images and inputs that all contain a SRC attribute, these are all contained within a parent DIV called #popupForm. I wish to use the .each method to loop through my form items (some are in child DIVs for styling) and replace part of the SRC depending on a match in the string - I won't go into why I want to do this but I have a site that has numerous themes. Here's what I have so far

```
var thisTheme = $("hiddenTheme").val(); // this is a theme variable
var $inputs = $('#popupForm :input');  // need to later add images here too

$inputs.children().each(function () {
$this.attr("src") = $this.attr("src").replace('whatIwantToReplace', thisTheme);
});
```

This should be fairly simple. Any help is appreciated.

---

Update

---

Got this to work with the following

```
// theming script
var thisTheme = $("#hiddenTheme").val();
var defaultTheme = "/midway/"

$('#popupForm img').each(function () {

    var thisSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    if (thisSRC.indexOf(defaultTheme) !== -1) {

        var new_src = $(this).attr('src').replace(defaultTheme, thisTheme);
        $(this).attr('src', new_src);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var thisTheme = $("hiddenTheme").val(); // this is a theme variable
var $inputs = $('#popupForm :input');  // need to later add images here too

$inputs.children().each(function () {
var new_src = $this.attr("src").replace('whatIwantToReplace', thisTheme);
$(this).attr('src', new_src);
});
```

Comment: @lonesomeday : he he :D right, it does nothing, my bad :) edited to "do something " :D
@Mike Sav : try now :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$this` doesn't mean anything here - a lot of authors will use `$this` to store the `$(this)` value to avoid calling the `$` jQuery function too many times, but you'll actually have to set `$this = $(this)` to be able to use it. Not setting it there should cause an error to be thrown.

Additionally, `$inputs.children()` seems strange because `input` elements cannot have children, nor can they have the `src` attribute.

And I believe you mean `#hiddenTheme` for the selector used to selecting the value of the input element, unless you actually have an element with the tag name `hiddenTheme`.

Finally, the code can be rewritten more nicely in this manner, avoiding the `each` loop altogether:

```
var thisTheme = $("#hiddenTheme").val();

$('#popupForm img').attr('src', function(index, value){
    return value.replace('whatIWantToReplace', thisTheme);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however when I switch my code with this Firebug gives me an error:

value is undefined
[Break On This Error] return value.replace('whatIWantToReplace', thisTheme); });

Comment: @MikeSav Look through the answer, I'm making certain assumptions here about the mistakes you made, are these assumptions correct?

Comment: Hi Okay, I best explain a bit better...

var thisTheme = $("#hiddenTheme").val(); is dervied for a hidden form item, the value of this is generated by server side code. When a user clicks a certain link a light box opens which has another form that contains images and inputs, all of these items contain a src attribute. I want jQuery to take a section of the src value and replace it with the variable thisTheme.